Why SMTP client-side emailing not working?
I'm trying to send emails out using smtp on client-side, however the emails aren't coming through. I even checked spam and nothing. I'm working on a project my boss gave me, don't worry about the security issues, that doesn't matter. I just want to send an email whenever someone logs in with their email as usernames saying, "someone accessed your account if it was.........you get what I mean". so, I will get the target email from the form input. In order to keep this code short, i will be sending a simple text gotten from the text area in the form named body, I was initially wanting to send html-built emails.
here is the html I'm using to achieve this, I already created credentials with elasticemail. com already. Don't worry, the credentials provided here is a demo.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Send Email</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Send Email</h1>
    <form id="email-form">
        <label for="to">To:</label>
        <input type="email" id="to" name="to" required><br><br>

        <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" required><br><br>

        <label for="body">Body:</label><br>
        <textarea id="body" name="body" rows="4" cols="50" required></textarea><br><br>

        <button type="button" onclick="sendEmail()">Send Email</button>
    </form>

    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>

    <script>
        function sendEmail() {
            const to = document.getElementById('to').value;
            const subject = document.getElementById('subject').value;
            const body = document.getElementById('body').value;

            Email.send({
                Host : "smtp.elasticemail.com",
                Username : "marvleybak@outlook.com",
                Password : "*****",
                port: 2525,
                To: to,
                From: 'marvleybak@outlook.com', // Your Outlook email address
                Subject: subject,
                Body: body
            }).then(
                message => alert('Email sent successfully')
            );
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Update
I got it to work using this same code here, I guess it just took some time for my credentials to get set into the elasticemail. com system. It started working after a while. However, the emails keeps going to spam. Is there a way to avoid this? It would seem I would have to verify a domain name with elasticemail but I don’t have money to pay for that I’m young and just learning, I really want to impress my teacher on this project. Help me please, even if the domain name looks stupid it’s not official as far as I can get a free custom domain email with it to verify as well. Even if they all have dumb names I just want to get it working.
Update
So I managed to get a domain name for $2 off godaddy. However it’s not hosted yet, how do I host it for free and have email services too ? I’m wondering how to make this domain work with elasticemail too.
Update
So I’ve done all the work,I hosted my domain with freehostia which of course their free hosting service does not have smtp services but we can get custom domain emails but they can’t send cause of no SMTP but we can receive and forward the mails to our normal gmail address. I fixed that with elastic email smtp free services. I just added their CNAME to my domain through Freehostia and their SPF, DKIM and DMARC as well and added the SMTP to my gmail account as a sending address and logged in my credentials. I received the gmail confirmation to add this new custom email as a sending address in my forwarding email and boom. I could send emails from gmail using my new custom domain email and it also works with my JavaScript I was planning to use. The only thing is when setting up the gmail smtp use 465 port but you can use the 2525 port smtp gives on your JavaScript use. Hope this helps anyone.

Probably not the best idea to have your password in the question.

You can’t make SMTP connections from a browser, you need a backend.

Is this HTML going to send the request to an HTTP/HTTPS -> SMTP gateway?

The password here is a demo, is just for show. Yes it’s sending a request to elasticemail where I have an email address verified as a from address. However it’s not a custom domain email, I don’t have money for that this is just a simple project. It’s an outlook as seen here. I got it to work, but the emails keep going to spam. Any ideas?
